# Python I can't find string in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I list all string which I want to search like this code.

```
for element in s2l:  
    print(element)
```

It show result like this

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Component Type
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\IPSEC\Policy\Local
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\iphlpsvc\config\Connectivity_Platform_Enabled
...
```

I want to search string in text file. So, change the code like this.

```
search_lst = open("tf.txt", "r" ,  encoding="utf8")

for element in s2l:  
    #print(element)

    for line in search_lst:

        if element in line:
            print(line)
```

when I run it show all data in tf.txt like this.

```
v 200 ScreenToClient

v 201 GetMessagePos

v 202 CallWindowProcW

v 203 IsWindowVisible

v 204 LoadBitmapW

v 205 CloseClipboard

v 206 SetClipboardData

v 207 EmptyClipboard

v 208 OpenClipboard

v 209 TrackPopupMenu

v 210 GetWindowRect

v 211 AppendMenuW

v 212 CreatePopupMenu

v 213 GetSystemMetrics

v 214 EndDialog

v 215 EnableMenuItem

v 216 GetSystemMenu

v 217 SetClassLongW

v 218 IsWindowEnabled

v 219 SetWindowPos

v 220 DialogBoxParamW

v 221 CheckDlgButton

v 222 CreateWindowExW

v 223 SystemParametersInfoW

v 224 RegisterClassW

v 225 GetDlgItemTextW

v 226 MessageBoxIndirectW

v 227 CharNextA

v 228 CharUpperW

v 229 CharPrevW

v 230 wvsprintfW

v 231 DispatchMessageW

v 232 PeekMessageW

v 233 wsprintfA

v 234 DestroyWindow

v 235 CreateDialogParamW

v 236 SetTimer

v 237 SetWindowTextW

v 238 PostQuitMessage

v 239 SetForegroundWindow

v 240 ShowWindow

v 241 wsprintfW

v 242 SendMessageTimeoutW

v 243 LoadCursorW

v 244 SetCursor

v 245 GetWindowLongW

v 246 GetSysColor

v 247 CharNextW

v 248 GetClassInfoW

v 249 ExitWindowsEx

v 250 IsWindow

v 251 GetDlgItem

v 252 SetWindowLongW

v 253 LoadImageW

v 254 GetDC

v 255 EnableWindow

v 256 InvalidateRect

v 257 SendMessageW

v 258 DefWindowProcW

v 259 BeginPaint

v 260 GetClientRect

v 261 FillRect

v 262 DrawTextW

v 263 EndPaint

v 264 FindWindowExW

v 265 CoTaskMemFree

v 266 OleInitialize

v 267 OleUninitialize

v 268 CoCreateInstance

v 269 C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll

v 270 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623

v 271 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Description

v 272 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enable Tracing

v 273 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\4

v 274 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming\RefreshProcName

v 275 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\UseHostnameAsAlias

v 276 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Description

v 277 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DevicePath

v 278 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HandleMgr

v 279 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Service\Enable

v 280 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Component Type

v 281 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshhttp

v 282 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Protocol

v 283 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\(Default)

v 284 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetTrace\Session

v 285 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\UseOldHostResolutionOrder

v 286 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\TransportDllPath

v 287 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Qecs\79619

v 288 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\CryptoAlgo

v 289 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Registration Date

v 290 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\CacheMgr\Publication

v 291 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Qecs\79623

v 292 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetTrace

v 293 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Version

v 294 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming

v 295 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups

v 296 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Config Clsid

v 297 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wshelper

v 298 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxPendingDownloads

v 299 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Diagnostics

v 300 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Service\PolicyRefreshInProgress

v 301 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Interface\{00000134-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

v 302 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

v 303 C:\Windows\System32\EAPQEC.DLL

v 304 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\CacheMgr\Publication

v 305 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wwancfg

v 306 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Tracing Level

v 307 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager\UtilityIndex

v 308 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\p2pnetsh

v 309 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\Publisher

v 310 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\캰=谘=齎

v 311 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager

v 312 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Validator Clsid

v 313 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxSimultaneousDownloads

v 314 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Config Clsid

v 315 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\(Default)

v 316 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Validator Clsid

v 317 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\BlockSize

v 318 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Qecs\79617

v 319 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\hnetmon

v 320 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache

v 321 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\CooperativeCaching

v 322 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{00000134-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\ProxyStubClsid32\(Default)

v 323 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Discovery

v 324 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\Roaming

v 325 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name

v 326 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber

v 327 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Component Type

v 328 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup

v 329 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager

v 330 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Publisher

v 331 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\PlumbIpsecPolicy

v 332 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\SourcePath

v 333 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nettrace

v 334 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxPendingOffers

v 335 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\rpc

v 336 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Qecs\79621

v 337 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UserenvDebugLevel

v 338 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wlancfg

v 339 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\Service

v 340 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Extensions\RemoteRpcDll

v 341 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name

v 342 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Vendor Name

v 343 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\SystemSetupInProgress

v 344 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxSimultaneousUploads

v 345 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\iphlpsvc\Config

v 346 C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll

v 347 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\Restricted\Seed

v 348 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\CacheMgr\Republication

v 349 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Registration Date

v 350 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\CooperativeCaching

v 351 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Download

v 352 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\Name

v 353 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\IPSEC\Policy\Local

v 354 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshipsec

v 355 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\whhelper

v 356 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\NetTrace\DebugFlags

v 357 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\CacheMgr\Republication

v 358 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621

v 359 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Info Clsid

v 360 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP

v 361 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\(Default)

v 362 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Config Clsid

v 363 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{00000134-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\ProxyStubClsid32

v 364 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\SecurityManager\Restricted

v 365 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\netiohlp

v 366 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\Connection

v 367 C:\Windows\System32\p2pcollab.dll

v 368 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\napmontr

v 369 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\Restricted

v 370 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming\RefreshDllName

v 371 C:\Windows\System32\DHCPQEC.DLL

v 372 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\ 0\Cryptﮐ

v 373 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\WcnNetsh

v 374 C:\Windows\System32\QAGENTRT.DLL

v 375 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\LdapClientIntegrity

v 376 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Vendor Name

v 377 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Info Clsid

v 378 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617

v 379 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Enabled

v 380 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Info Clsid

v 381 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\ServerRole

v 382 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager

v 383 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Friendly Name

v 384 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Peers\Connection

v 385 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\GpSvcDebugLevel

v 386 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Protocol

v 387 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager\DiscoveryProviderDllPath

v 388 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Friendly Name

v 389 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Download

v 390 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager\MinBackoffWindow

v 391 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Vendor Name

v 392 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

v 393 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\HostedCache

v 394 C:\Windows\system32

v 395 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetTrace

v 396 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dot3cfg

v 397 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Validator Clsid

v 398 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\UI

v 399 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist

v 400 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Component Type

v 401 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\DoNotUseSSL

v 402 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\ClientAuth

v 403 C:\Windows\System32\napipsec.dll

v 404 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh

v 405 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Description

v 406 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Registration Date

v 407 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\iphlpsvc\config\Connectivity_Platform_Enabled

v 408 C:\Windows\System32\tsgqec.dll

v 409 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\fwcfg

v 410 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Enabled

v 411 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager

v 412 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\authfwcfg

v 413 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Setup

v 414 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Vendor Name

v 415 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\NetTrace\Scenarios

v 416 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Enabled

v 417 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE

v 418 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshwfp

v 419 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Peers\Connection

v 420 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\Name

v 421 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\TransportDllPath

v 422 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

v 423 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Service

v 424 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Extensions

v 425 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups\(Default)

v 426 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\2

v 427 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dhcpclient

v 428 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\HandleMgr

v 429 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Version

v 430 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Discovery

v 431 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619

v 432 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Upload

v 433 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Friendly Name

v 434 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Info Clsid

v 435 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Description

v 436 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\PolicyProvider

v 437 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Config Clsid

v 438 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Enabled

v 439 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Validator Clsid

v 440 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79619\Version

v 441 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Upload

v 442 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System

v 443 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\HostedCache\Connection

v 444 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Friendly Name

v 445 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager

v 446 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\NumBlocksPerSegment

v 447 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Component Type

v 448 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\UtilityIndex

v 449 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79623\Version

v 450 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79621\Registration Date

v 451 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming\ForceRoamingDetect

v 452 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade

v 453 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NapAgent\LocalConfig

v 454 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager\RepubQuorumSize

v 455 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist\SecurityManager

v 456 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\PeerDist

v 457 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\Name
```

How to search only match string with python ?

Answer (score 2):

Your items have a new line at the trailing if you don't want to match them too you should check the membership with striped string (`str.strip()` method), or check the membership of the lines of your file with the list which is more optimized and pythonic:

```
with open("tf.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as search_lst:    
    for line in search_lst:
        if line in s2l:
            print(line)
```